# HTML select change value based on Database entry with vbhtml

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, razor

I want to edit some Data in a HTML select Element:

```
<select id="Photoshop" name="Photoshop">
                <option selected value= 0> </option>
                <option value=2>Installieren</option>
                <option value=0>Nicht Installieren</option>
            </select>
```

I want to get this selected, based on the Value which is in the Database. (If I select Value 2, it should stay Value 2 after reload, now  every time I reload it resets to 0)

I've tried different things with JavaScript (Newbie in js here), but it didn't work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Photoshop").val("Model.Photoshop")  
    })
</script>
```

changes the value to Null

the code block from vbhtml wont want to work too. I can get the Data, but cant change it in the selectbox (doesn't "know" the selectbox)

There should be a another way, to get the Database Data, at the best without js. (Model.Photoshop should do its Job)
I haven't found something similar, which can fix this kind of problem. My researches were hopeless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is kinda simple.

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Photoshop").val("@Model.Photoshop")
    })
</script>
```

as you can see, you just need to Type @Model.Photoshop, instead of Model.Photoshop.

If this Value is not in the select list, you will se a blank Space.

AR